# How to create a variable with a value of its self + another variable

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables

I need my carts page to be able to remember the total price of items, I have `3 items` and they are all the same price (to make things simpler on my self). A user can submit the quantity using a form on another page. What I need the code to do remember the quantity for `item 1`, then when `item 2` is submitted via the form it will add the quantity of the previous with the quantity submitted by the new item. So far iv gotten it to send the quantity through the form into the array, then it can be called whenever it's needed, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to make it add the previous qty with the new one to give me a total price.

I don't think all the code is needed to help with this so I'll just post what I think is needed. If you want to see it all though just ask and I'll edit my post to include it.

My code:

```
<link id='stylecss' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/cartstyle.css">
<link id='stylecss' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
require_once("head.php");
?>
<?php
require_once("nav.php");
?>

<?php
var_dump ($_POST);
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
$_SESSION['cart']=[];
}
$cart = &$_SESSION['cart'];
$movieName = $_POST['movie_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['qty'];

if(isset($moveName)) {
$currentQuantity = $cart[$movieName];
$cart[$movieName] = $currentQuantity + $quantity;
} else {
$cart[$movieName] = $quantity;

}
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>

<div class="shopping-cart">
<!-- Title -->
<div class="title">
  Shopping Bag
</div>

<!-- Product #1 -->
<div class="item">
  <div class="image">
    <?php
    foreach ($cart as $movieName=> $quantity) {
    if ($movieName == 'Inception') {
      echo '<img src="incepcart.jpg" alt="got"/>';
    }
  }
?>
  </div>

  <div class="description">
<?php
foreach ($cart as $movieName=> $quantity) {
if ($movieName == 'Inception') {
  echo "<p>" . $movieName . "x" . $quantity;
  }
}
?>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Product #2 -->
<div class="item">
  <div class="image">
    <?php
    foreach ($cart as $movieName => $quantity) {
    if ($movieName == 'Game of Thrones: Season 1') {
      echo '<img src="gotcart.jpg" alt="got"/>';
  }
}
    ?>
  </div>
 <div class="description">
<?php
foreach ($cart as $movieName => $quantity) {
if ($movieName == 'Game of Thrones: Season 1') {
  echo "<p>" . $movieName . "x" . $quantity;
  }
}
?>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Product #3 -->
<div class="item">
  <div class="image">
    <?php
    foreach ($cart as $movieName=> $quantity) {
    if ($movieName == 'Friends Season 1') {
      echo '<img src="friendscart.jpg" alt="got"/>';
  }
}
    ?>
  </div>

  <div class="description">
<?php
foreach ($cart as $movieName=> $quantity) {
if ($movieName == 'Friends Season 1') {
  echo "<p>" . $movieName . "x" . $quantity;
  }
}
?>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="rhsidee">
 <?php
    if ($movieName == 'Game of Thrones: Season 1') {

}
$total = $_POST['qty'] * 19.99;

    echo "<p>Total <span class\"price\" style=\"color:black\"><b>$total</b></span>"
    ?>

</div>
      <?php 
      echo $currentQuantity * 20
      ?>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



<form action="product.php">
<button class="prod" type="submit">Continue Shopping </button>
</form>



<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<?php
require_once("footer.php");
?>
```

And the code for one of my forms that submits data into cart.php:

```
<form action="carttest.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="movie_name" value= "Game of Thrones: Season 1" />
   <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "M01" />
   <br>
</select>
<div class="widthc">
   <button class="prod" id="minus">−</button>
<input type="number" name="qty" value="0" id="qty" min="0" max="15"/>
<button class="prod" id="plus">+</button>
<br><br>
<button class="prod" type="submit">  Submit</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: your isset($moveName) has a typoed variable, it won't help your code

Comment: WHERE do you set `$currentQuantity ` to its original value?

Comment: hmm i thought doing $currentQuantity + $quantity would give $currentQuantity its value. do i need to have a it so $currentQuantity has a value or 0 to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @sudhansu, Session is the best option here, What you can do here is create a session's key-value pair per item.

for e.g. onsubmit a quantity for item_CNT you just set a session value with following keys in it.

```
$_SESSION[itemCNT][quantity] = 100;
$_SESSION[itemCNT][name] = 'name';
$_SESSION[itemCNT][id] = 71273928739;
```

you can increment CNT as an when user adds quantity for a particular item.

You can loop through the SESSION array whenever you need it. you can access this session from any page.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to reply, i do have a session active on all my pages and it is able to remmeber data even if i click off the cart page. I just want it to be able to add the quantity from item 1 onto item 2,3,4 and so on. Of course it will need to remember the added quantities and possible put them into a array so it can remember the 'currentQuantity' of all items. Ill also add in my code so you guys can get a better understanding .

Answer (score 0):

To save those cart value. You can do it in three ways.

- Session
- Cookie
- Db

If you want to keep track on user's cart. you can create cart table. and put the value of quantity and item id inside the cart page. and if you need value for a specific session, just store it inside session. and if you want to store it inside user's browser. just store it in cookie.

Comment: i do have a session active, i only posted the code i thought would be needed to answer the question. if u like i can post the rest